# Python recursively execute try except while condition is fulfilled

Tags: python, list, csv, text

I want to iterate a text file line by line and search for a Pattern and extract entities out of it. But, a couple of pattern extracted has multi-line characteristics which get lost when I iterate it line by line.

Right now, I am using a `try-except` block and appending the next line to the current line something like:

```
try:
    id_value, utterance, prediction = process(line + ' ' + lines[n + 1])
except AttributeError:
    # Handle bad data
    try:
        id_value, utterance, prediction = process(line + ' ' + lines[n + 1] + ' ' + lines[n + 2])
    except AttributeError:
        # Handle bad data
        try:
            id_value, utterance, prediction = process(
                line + ' ' + lines[n + 1] + ' ' + lines[n + 2] + ' ' + lines[n + 3])
```

---

Here's the data:

data.txt

```
[22 Aug 2019 13:25:12] [ID:9ea1566460506294]     INFO [139921763325696] (ModelClassification:056) - Model classification for utterance_1 is 1
[22 Aug 2019 13:26:06] [ID:7ea1566460117776]     INFO [139921771718400] (ModelClassification:056) - Model classification for  utterance_2
 is 1
[22 Aug 2019 13:26:16] [ID:71d1566460492762]     INFO [139921771718400] (ModelClassification:056) - Model classification for utterance_3 is 0
```

---

As you can see

```
[22 Aug 2019 13:26:06] [ID:7ea1566460117776]     INFO [139921771718400] (ModelClassification:056) - Model classification for  utterance_2
 is 1
```

Extends 2 lines upon iterating line by line.

**code**

```
import re

matching_string = 'Model classification for'
id_start_string = '[ID:'
id_end_string = ']'


def process(line):
    start_idx = line.find(id_start_string)
    end_idx = [s.start() for s in re.finditer(id_end_string, line)]
    for end in end_idx:
        if end > start_idx:
            # Get first index greater than start string index
            end_idx = end
            break
    id_value = line[start_idx + len(id_start_string): end_idx]
    groups = re.search('Model classification for (.*) is (0|1)', line).groups()
    utterance = groups[0]
    prediction = groups[1]
    return id_value, utterance, prediction


with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for n, line in enumerate(lines):
        # Search for pattern in string
        if matching_string in line:
            try:
                id_value, utterance, prediction = process(line)
            except AttributeError:
                 print('Bad data')
                 print(line)
            print(id_value, utterance, prediction)
```

Can there be a recursive solution to my problem? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit -**

```
lines = ['22 Aug 2019 13:25:12] [ID:9ea1566460506294]     INFO [139921763325696] (ModelClassification:056) - Model classification for utterance_1 is 1', '[22 Aug 2019 13:26:06] [ID:7ea1566460117776]     INFO [139921771718400] (ModelClassification:056) - Model classification for  utterance_2', ' is 1', '[22 Aug 2019 13:26:16] [ID:71d1566460492762]     INFO [139921771718400] (ModelClassification:056) - Model classification for utterance_3 is 0 ']
```

Comment: Can you please extend your code to not depend on a unspecified `data.txt` file? Just hardcode an array of strings, which is what you get in `lines` anyway and which is hopefully not causing the problems (verify that, please!).

Comment: edited my question. `data.txt` is specified.

Comment: Nah, don't add edit sections. Extracting and providing a [mcve] should be your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the original question (and without considering what `process` actually does), iterate over progressively larger combinations:

```
value = line
for extra in lines[n+1:]:
    value = value + " " + extra
    try:
        id_value, utterance, prediction = process(value)
        break
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find a line in a file. You can use re.findall() for that

```
import re
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read()

output = re.findall(r'some regex pattern', text)
output1 = re.findall(r'some other pattern', text)
output2 = re.findall(r'another pattern', text)

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(output)
    f.write(output1)
    f.write(output2)
```

If you want to do it recursively you can but re.findall sounds like what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to capture with the newline you could modify your regex to accept a possible newline (whitespace) character:

```
r'Model classification for (.*)\s? is (0|1)'
```

Run this over the whole file using re.findall

Comment: This won't work because the continuation part is in the next iteration.

Comment: Sorry, don't run the regular expression over every line. Run it over the whole file using re.findall. Then you can just iterate over the matches.

Answer (score 0):

I will just write my own solution for this problem. I met something similar in my app.
as an input, your sample-log will be used.

Let's say we have a file with logs ( I complicated them a bit):

```
[22 Aug 2019 13:25:12] [ID:9ea1566460506294]     INFO [139921763325696] 
(ModelClassification:056) - Mod
el classification for utterance_1 is 1
[22 Aug 2019 13:26:06] [ID:7ea1566460117776]     INFO [13992177
1718400] (ModelClassification:056) - Model classificat
ion for  utterance_2
 is 1
[22 Aug 2019 13:26:16] [ID:71d1566460492762]     INFO [139921771718400] (ModelC
lassification:056) - Model classification for utterance_3 is 0
```

Now, my goal is collect a single log. Single log is what starts from data and ends with another line, which starts with next data. (the file contains a lot of single logs)
When I parse properly a single log, I can find regex.

code:

```
import re

START_LINE_REGEX = re.compile(r'^\[\d+')
MAIN_MATCHER = re.compile(r'(\[ID:\w+\]).* Model classification for (.*) is (0|1)')

def read_file(file_path):
    """
    Read file from path, and return iterator.
    """
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        return iter(f.read().splitlines())

def verify_line(line):
    """
    Check if line starts with proper regex. 
    """
    return True if START_LINE_REGEX.match(line) else False

def single_log(iterator):
    """
    Generator, parse log.
    """
    content = [next(iterator)]
    for line in iterator:
        state = verify_line(line)
        if state:
            yield "".join(content)
            content = [line]
        else:
            content.append(line)
    yield "".join(content)

def get_patterns(log):
    """
    Read values from given regex and a one, big line ( a single log )
    """
    matcher = MAIN_MATCHER.search(log)
    if matcher:
        return matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3)
    else:
        print("Could not get groups from '{}'".format(log))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    iterator = read_file('stackoverflow.log')

    gen = single_log(iterator)
    for index, log in enumerate(gen):
        print("{}: {}".format(index, log))
        print("Found regexes: {}".format(get_patterns(log)))
```

Results:

```
0: [22 Aug 2019 13:25:12] [ID:9ea1566460506294]     INFO [139921763325696] 
(ModelClassification:056) - Model classification for utterance_1 is 1
Found regexes: ('[ID:9ea1566460506294]', 'utterance_1', '1')
1: [22 Aug 2019 13:26:06] [ID:7ea1566460117776]     INFO [139921771718400]         
(ModelClassification:056) - Model classification for  utterance_2 is 1
Found regexes: ('[ID:7ea1566460117776]', ' utterance_2', '1')
2: [22 Aug 2019 13:26:16] [ID:71d1566460492762]     INFO [139921771718400]         
(ModelClassification:056) - Model classification for utterance_3 is 0
Found regexes: ('[ID:71d1566460492762]', 'utterance_3', '0')
```

Ofc it depends on start log format, but if you improve regex, I'm sure it will be more valuable than dancing with index in lists.